# How do I disable the "Customize Toolbar" from the Quick Access toolbar in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an application I am developing with Access 2010.  In certain circumstances I have to limit the users to a very limited subset of the application.  This implies a limited Ribbon - by setting a dbProperties to "AllowAllMenus" to false, and changing the File menu (using a Custom Backstage ribbon).

This blocks most off the holes that would allow the user to get back to full menus, and then have access to data I would rather he didn't.

However, there is a hole in this process.  The quick access toolbar as a little drop down arrow on the end of it with a hover of "Customise Toolbar". Using it drops down a menu with "More Commands...".  Clicking on that drops you into the same dialog box you get when you chose "Options" from the File Menu (disabling of which was the prime purpose of my Backstage Ribbon change).

I can of course do the following in VBA

```
DoCmd.ShowToolbar "Ribbon",acToolbarNo
```

but that hides all the menus and Quick Access Toolbar completely.  I don't want that, because I still need to allow the user to set up filters and toggle them on an off from the data they do see.

I can't find any other reference to how to block up this  security hole in the applcation.  Does anyone have any ideas on how?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have your custom ribbon, make sure that you have assigned: startFromScratch="true".

However, this will disable not only "More Commands..", but all the other options of QAT dropdown list as well, except "Show Below the Ribbon".

Comment: I will try this out.  It is currently shown as false, because I do want some of the standard ribbon commands to be available and I have only redefined the file menu.  Does the QAT have a name that can be used to redefine the QAT?

Comment: here is more information about QAT

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940502(v=vs.85).aspx

if you still need standard commands, you can add them as buttons to the left from dropdown arrow.